# TCP Packet Dump Retransmission Detection

Tags: tcp, wireshark, packet-sniffers

I am wondering how, in detail, a program like wireshark detects duplicates from retransmission in a TCP stream. I've looked at the RFCs regarding TCP but haven't quite been able to figure out how it works. I'd very much appreciate a clear explanation.

An example situation that confused me was the following:

```
*C: 1227 + len = 1687
 C: 1847+ len = 2299
 S: ACK 2299
*C: 2299+len = 2751
*C: 2751+len = 3203
 S: ACK 2751
```

Where the * indicates packets with duplicate payloads. How does wireshark and or TCP function to detect and discard the duplicates?

Answer (score 0):

According to the book 《Troubleshooting with wireshark》

> Wireshark defines a packet as a Retransmission if the following conditions are met:
>
> The segment contains data or has the SYN or FIN bits set to 1.
>
> The segment does not advance the sequence number
>
> The Retransmission is not triggered by Duplicate ACKs
>
> The segment arrives > 3 ms later than the previous packet with a higher sequence number

and you see the below picture to make clear

[image]